# Update state (useState) and navigate (history.push) to another page.... is it correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm learning ReactJS and hooks from scratch and I am not pretty sure if the below code follows the good practices.

```
  const [showSpinner, setShowSpinner] = useState(false);
  ....
  const onSaveHandler = async () => {
    setShowSpinner(true);
    try {
      for (const skillState of skillStates) {
        const { id, state, originalState, isNew } = skillState;
        const userSkill = userSkills.find((userSkill) => userSkill.id === id);
        if (isNew) {
          if (!!state) {
            await DataStore.save(userSkill);
          }
        } else {
          if (state !== originalState) {
            if (!!state) {
              await DataStore.save(userSkill);
            } else {
              await DataStore.delete(userSkill);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    await setCurrentUser();
    setShowSpinner(false);

    history.push(MY_PROFILE_URL);
  };
```

Basically, this function is associated with an event handler inside a function component. When the user clicks on the "Save" button, this function is called, show a spinner, save the information in the Datastore and when finishes to save the information in the datastore it updates the spinner state and navigates to another page.

My concern is that I update the component state, so this component will re-render, and also I navigate to another page when the current component is running the re-render cycle.

What is it the best approach to face this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any issues when navigating right after updating the state.
If you are using class component and inside render() function you call setState then React will warns with a warning message in the console of developer tool.
Btw, I think you should use Promise.all to handle a list of promises, instead of using individual awaits, it will make your code more readable.